# Can one write an open interval as a union in two different ways?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can one write an open interval say $(0,1)$ in the following two different manners: $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ and $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$. Are these two unions equal?

Comment: Indeed they are

Comment: Yes.  Think about what numbers are not in each union.

Comment: Here's a way to think if it.  The number 1- 1/n is in the interval (0, 1 - 1/(n+1)) so it doesn't matter if it is included in (0, 1 - 1/n) or (0, 1-1/n] or not; it will be included in (0,1 - 1/(n+1)) any way so it gets included in both those unions.

Comment: You should either start the indexing at 2, or define (0,0) = (0,0] = empty set (which is perfectly acceptable to me but others might object).

Comment: I changed the upper limit of your your bigcups to use only "\infty" rather than "n=\infty". In no paper or textbook will you ever see the index repeated in the upper limit of sums, products, unions, intersections, etc.

Comment: @fleablood For $a\ge b$, $(a,b) = \{x\mid a < x \text{ and } x < b\} = \emptyset$, and similarly $(a,b] = \emptyset$: there simply are no such $x$. So $(0,0)$ and $(0,0]$ really are equal to $\emptyset$ — no statement of convention or special-case definition is needed. Who's gonna object? ;) But good of you to point out that there's "something special" about the case $n=1$.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for the notational correction.

Comment: @BrianO That's my thinking, but a lot of abuses can arise not to mention confusion to students.  One might conclude A = union (a, b) and conclude  A isn't empty because the a,b all exist.  or that $A^c$ = [b, a]$ consisting of intervals when [a,a] is actually a set of a single point.  And in *my* solution I said (0, 1 - 1/n)$\cup$ 1/(n-1) = (0,1 - 1/n). In which case I damned well *better* note I'm only referring to n>1.

Comment: Also very confusing $a < b$ so $(b, a) = \emptyset$  this can and does come up and can mislead.  In analysis one will be asked to prove that every open set in R is a union of open intervals.  One can be misled (I speak from experience) and if one concludes there complement of (a,b)U(c,d) is [b,c] therefore every closed set is a union of closed intervals...

Comment: @fleablood Indeed that gets tricky, "effortless" manipulations of interval bounds when taking complements. Too tricky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equal. For every real number $0 < x < 1$, we can find a positive integer $n$, such that $x < 1-\frac{1}{n}$, so 
$$
x \in (0, 1-\frac1n) \subset (0,1-\frac1n].
$$
This shows that $(0,1)$ is a subset of both unions.

Conversely,  no real number outside $(0,1)$ belongs to any of the intervals used to define the unions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equal.

You can write $(0,1)$ in infinitely ways. This do not depend neither of the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ nor the set itself. If a set has more than one element you can write it in many ways.

It is different if you impose some other condition. Then it may be one, infinitely or can be no way.

Answer (score 0):

This is silly but fun (and it works!)

$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty}(0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$

$= \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\{(0,1-\frac{1}{n}) \cup \{1 -{1 \over n}\}\}$

$=....\cup\{(0,1-\frac{1}{n}) \cup {\frac{1}{n}}\}\cup\{(0,1-\frac{1}{n+1}) \cup \{1 -{1 \over n}\}\}\cup...$

$= ....\cup\{\{1 -{1 \over {n-1}}\}\cup(0,1-\frac{1}{n})\}\cup \{\{1 -{1 \over {n}}\}\cup(0,1-\frac{1}{n+1})\}\cup...$

$= \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\{\{1 -{1 \over {n-1}}\}\cup(0,1-\frac{1}{n}) \}$; but $1- \frac 1 {n-1} \in (0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ so

$=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty}(0,1-\frac{1}{n})$

====

Oh, there is a concern, but it is also a concern of the original statement.

The notation $(0, 0]= (0, 0) = (0, 1 - 1/1) = \emptyset$ must be defined.

In my solution the first term of $\{1 - {1 \over {n -1}} \cup (0, 1 - 1/n)$ must actually start at $n = 2$.  The *very* first term is simply $(0, 1 - 1/1) = \emptyset$

Comment: No need to worry about $n=1$. $(0,0) = (0,0] = \emptyset$, for real. See my comment to the original question.

Comment: Yes but *I*  state $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\{\{1 -{1 \over {n-1}}\}\cup(0,1-\frac{1}{n}) \}$ I need to make an exception that for n=1, I am *not* including the "number" 1 - 1/(n-1).

Comment: My bad: sorry, I overlooked your $n-1$, I was still thinking about your comment to the question proper, & my reply there. Yes, it's different here.

Comment: If always felt I should be able to write (a,a) or [b>, a] and such as the empty set but have had people say .. "uh, what?"